# Mysql if statement ignoring first condition

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have an if statement in mysql procedure like this:

```
if myQuery like '%فواید%' or myQuery like '%مضرات%' or myQuery like 
'%خواص%' or myQuery like '%عوارض%' then
set  EHSfour= b'1';
end if;
```

To my surprise, I found out the if statement above ignores myQuery like '%فواید%'. It checks other conditions and sets `EHSfour = 1` when `myQuery is like '%مضرات%' or '%خواص%' or '%عوارض%'` but not when `myQuery` is `like '%فواید%'`.

Why the hell mysql works like that? In what scenario mysql might misbehave like that?

mysql version is 5.7 and I'm using mysql workbench 6.3 CE.

update:
In my code I have :

```
if EHSfour = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 4;
```

and then:

```
update new_tbl_health set EHS_kind = myEHSkind where ID = myID;
```

Here's my entire procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fillEHSKind`()
BEGIN
declare myEHSkind int default 0;
declare EHSone,EHStwo,EHSthree,EHSfour bit;
declare myID int(11);
declare myQuery varchar(500);
declare v_finished integer default 0;
declare myCursor cursor for select ID,Query from new_tbl_health;
declare continue handler for not found set v_finished = 1;
open myCursor;
myLoop: loop
fetch myCursor into myID,myQuery;
if v_finished = 1 then
leave myLoop;
end if;

set EHSone = b'0';
set EHStwo = b'0';
set EHSthree = b'0';
set EHSfour = b'0';
set myEHSkind = 0;

if myQuery like '%بیمارستان%' or myQuery like '%دکتر%' or myQuery like 
'%پزشک%' then
set  EHSone= b'1';
end if;

if myQuery like '%بیماری%' or myQuery like '%مریضی%'
set EHStwo = b'1';
end if;

if myQuery like '%علایم%' or myQuery like '%نشانه%' or myQuery like 
'%علت%' or myQuery like '%خارش%'  then
set EHSthree = b'1';
end if;

if myQuery like '%فواید%' or myQuery like '%مضرات%' or myQuery like 
'%خواص%' 
or myQuery like '%عوارض%' then
set  EHSfour= b'1';
end if;

if EHSone = b'1' and EHStwo = b'1' and EHSthree=b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 8;
elseif EHSone = b'1' and EHStwo = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 5;
elseif EHSone = b'1' and EHSthree = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 6;
elseif EHStwo = b'1' and EHSthree = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 7;
elseif EHSone = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 1;
elseif EHStwo = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 2;
elseif EHSthree = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 3;
elseif EHSfour = b'1' then
set myEHSkind = 4;
end if;

update new_tbl_health set EHS_kind = myEHSkind where ID = myID;
end loop myLoop;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use if in this way but very probably, your if statement affects only the first row which matches the condition.

If you want to update all the rows that match the condition you could try the following:

```
update #tableName set EHSfour= b'1' where (myQuery like '%فواید%' or myQuery like '%مضرات%' or myQuery like '%خواص%' or myQuery like '%عوارض%');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That might work!
My question is why it is working like that? Is it a bug?
I do have a bit more code in my procedure but I'm almost sure there is nothing to do with my code

Comment: Please check the update of the answer. As I mentioned there, very probably, your if statement affects only the first row which matches the condition.

Ideally, you could share the entire piece of code, to have all the context of your query.

Comment: No it does not affect just one row. It updates all rows that match the condition except the ones which are like '%فواید%'